Combine upload image with chart.js
Is it possible to upload an image and then use it as a background in Chart.JS? I found two separate codes but cannot combine them. It is possible to combine the two codes?


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var img = document.querySelector('img');
          img.onload = () => {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);  // no longer needed, free memory
          }
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url

              }
      });
});

const image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg';

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: "pink"
    }]
  },
  options: {},
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customImage',
    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
      if (image.complete) {
        const ctx = chart.ctx;
        const {
          top,
          left,
          width,
          height
        } = chart.chartArea;
        const x = left + width - image.width;
        const y = top + height - image.height;
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
      } else {
        image.onload = () => chart.draw();
      }
    }

  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
        

    
<input type='file' />
<br><img id="myImg" src="#">
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>




Sure it's possible - you just have to draw your chart after the user has selected an image. (Or trigger a re-draw in that case.)

Maybe I am wrong, but is the chart in the example not drawn after the user selected the image? Is it possible to give a nudge in the right direction?

Well yes, which is why I said you'd need to change that. Basically, you just need to initialize the chart in the image load handler (remove var img = ... from in there, and work with the global image variable instead.) If you want to draw the chart again, if the user selects a different image - then you will need to destroy the existing chart first though, otherwise the library will throw an error.
